# Grouping another col'n value from one col'n value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Please help me on this, this should return value of Dollars where the insert is standard

'[image]'

Comment: Please paste code as code blocks, not as images.

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need `[]` because collision with pandas function [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html), also better is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select one column of `DataFrame`:

```
No1 = card.loc[card['insert'] == 'Standard', 'dollars']
#original solution
#No1 = card.dollars[card['insert'] =='Standard']
```

Comment: No1 = card.dollars[card['insert'] =='Standard']

Comment: This is also working :-)